# A mathematical equation creates Item spacing (distance) problem in itemized environment

Tags: beamer, itemize

I'm here facing a problem which can be reflected in the below figure
[image]

I'm using nested itemized, however, what I need is that the equation should appear in the same way as text appears in the previous item. Meaning equation and time of use bullet should have the same space to make a document in good shape. Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{%
\olditem\vspace{8pt}}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}
\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667} 
\usecolortheme[named=UBCblue]{structure}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{AAAAAA}
 \begin{itemize}
\item Electricity pricing tariff
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Time  of  use  (TOU)  pricing  scheme
     \end{itemize}
\item Cost function
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{equation} YU_T=\sum_{{t}=1}^{\mathcal{T}}\sum_{\mathcal{A}=1}^{\mathcal{A_S}}\bigg(\mathcal{E}(t)\times \pi(t)\times\gamma(t)
\bigg).
\end{equation} 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change to inline math mode. Thus, change

```
\item \begin{equation} YU_T=\sum_{{t}=1}^{\mathcal{T}}\sum_{\mathcal{A}=1}^{\mathcal{A_S}}
      \bigg(\mathcal{E}(t)\times \pi(t)\times\gamma(t)\bigg).
\end{equation}
```

to

```
\item $\displaystyle YU_T=\sum_{{t}=1}^{\mathcal{T}}\sum_{\mathcal{A}=1}^{\mathcal{A_S}}
     \Bigl(\mathcal{E}(t)\times \pi(t)\times\gamma(t)\Bigr)$.
```

Note that I also suggest reducing the size of the parentheses from `\bigg` to `\Big` (or even just `\big`).

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment: AFAICT, the three `\addtobeamertemplate` directives do not affect line spacing. (For sure, they do not affect the line spacing in the frame you showed. As stated, the three directives just set the length of `\textwidth` equal to `1\textwidth`, i.e., they don't seem to do anything meaningful at all.)

If you don't want the lavish line spacing provided by the redefined `\item` directive, just use `\olditem`. The upper half of the following screenshot shows the spacing generated by the use of `\item`, while the lower half shows the line effect of using `\olditem`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
% \usepackage{amsmath} % 'amsmath'mis loaded automatically by 'beamer'
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\olditem\vspace{8pt}}

%% I've deliberately commented out the next three lines:
%\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}}{}
%\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{\setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}}{}
%\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{\setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}}{}
\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667} 
\usecolortheme[named=UBCblue]{structure}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{AAAAAA}
\textcolor{red}{Using \texttt{\string\item}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Electricity pricing tariff
\begin{itemize}
   \item Time  of  use  (TOU)  pricing  scheme
\end{itemize}
\item Cost function
\begin{itemize}
   \item $\displaystyle YU_T=\sum_{{t}=1}^{\mathcal{T}}  
     \sum_{\mathcal{A}=1}^{\mathcal{A_S}}
     \bigl(\mathcal{E}(t)\times \pi(t)\times\gamma(t)\bigr)$. 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\bigskip
\textcolor{red}{Using \texttt{\string\olditem}}
\begin{itemize}
\olditem Electricity pricing tariff
\begin{itemize}
  \olditem Time  of  use  (TOU)  pricing  scheme
\end{itemize}
\olditem Cost function
\begin{itemize}
  \olditem $\displaystyle YU_T=\sum_{{t}=1}^{\mathcal{T}}  
     \sum_{\mathcal{A}=1}^{\mathcal{A_S}}
     \bigl(\mathcal{E}(t)\times \pi(t)\times\gamma(t)\bigr)$. 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, can you just answer one more thing, how I can change the line spacing of items in a specific frame.  These lines codes enable me to change line spacing for all the document not a specific frame \addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}

Comment: @Shane - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: Once again, Thanks for the answer. highly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply transform your equation to inline with \displaystyle?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{%
    \olditem\vspace{8pt}}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}
\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667} 
\usecolortheme[named=UBCblue]{structure}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{AAAAAA}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Electricity pricing tariff
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Time  of  use  (TOU)  pricing  scheme
    \end{itemize}
    \item Cost function
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $\displaystyle{YU_T=\sum_{{t}=1}^{\mathcal{T}}\sum_{\mathcal{A}=1}^{\mathcal{A_S}}\bigg(\mathcal{E}(t)\times \pi(t)\times\gamma(t)
        \bigg)}$
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered_beamer_frame]

Comment: Thanks and Perfect @Ivan

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an equation number, start the item with a `minipage` of the relevant size:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{%
\olditem\vspace{8pt}}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
 \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{%
 \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{%
 \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}
\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667}
\usecolortheme[named=UBCblue]{structure}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{AAAAAA}
 \begin{itemize}
\item Electricity pricing tariff
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Time of use (TOU) pricing scheme
     \end{itemize}
\item Cost function
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{equation} YU_T=\sum_{{t}=1}^{\mathcal{T}}\sum_{\mathcal{A}=1}^{\mathcal{A_S}}\bigg(\mathcal{E}(t)\times \pi(t)\times\gamma(t)
\bigg).
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]